# Blender 2.81, Why are my Light and other settings GONE?

Tags: interface, light

I have literally no light settings available.  I have the same problem with material settings.  Almost all of my material settings are gone also. It works fine on an older saved file.  Also works fine if I create a new file.  All light sources in this scene display ZERO settings such as color, power, radius. :(

What did I do to make them disappear? I have tried everything and searched to no avail.  Unfortunately, none of the suggestions has fixed it so far.

I have also downloaded and reinstalled 2.81 with no difference.

[image]

Comment: is it also a problem with other light types? What happens if you add a new light to the scene? What happens in a newly created file?

Comment: Yes, this happens with all light types in the scene, both old ones and newly added ones.  A new file works just fine though. All settings available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally**, **SOLVED**,
I still do not know what caused it, but I right clicked on the modeling tab, deleted it, and then added it back.  Everything now works normally.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should check if you are using Workbench Render Engine, Because it does not support light properties.

[image]

[image]

You need to use:

1- Eevee Render Engine

2- Cycles Render Engine

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: visible]

That happens when you have hidden "layers" in an old version of Blender and open it with 2.8x. To show the items click the tv and camera-icons to make everything visible again.

See the second image, click the tv-screen and everything is visible again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this didn't work.  That changes the visibility in the viewport not the visibility of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% on this, but blender deletes unused data, this might have happened to your sun
[image]

Checking this dropdown might give you some extra info on what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, All of my light sources appear in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  It works fine in all modes except MODELING mode.  UV editing, Layout, rendering, compositing modes, all work fine.  This does not seem right.  Is this a bug? Should I report it as a bug?

Could someone verify that this happens to them also?

Comment: Can you share the Blend-file?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in version 2.93 by switching render engines.
While using Workbench I was unable to view settings for objects and lights.